# How to validate BPEL programmatically?

Tags: validation, bpel

I want to validate BPEL programmatically. I use the openESB version of it but it would suffice having a validator for the standard BPEL or for other BPEL engines. Is there something out there that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse BPEL Designer can validate BPEL processes. You could also download the BPEL XSD from OASIS and use an XML tool to validate your process against this schema. A 3rd option is the compiler of Apache ODE, which also validates the process model.